# Early 90s Jungle themed christian childrens Musical

Tags: music

There was a popular Jungle themed christian children's musical, in the early 90's.

It centered on a young lion cub worried about growing up and becoming King (not Lion King).

It had several fun characters in it, including one that liked to play tennis on Tuesdays (English accent).

Does anyone know the name of this musical, and maybe who wrote it or performed it so I can find it?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Why are you asking this question on Christianity.SE?

Comment: In my search, I found a similar question asked with good responses from this site. That is why I asked...hoping to get the same kind of results.

Answer (score 2):

### Here's the lowdown, background info:

> Since 1990, Jeff Parker, Nathan Carlson, Phil Lollar and David Buller
>   have worked together to entertain and enrich children and their
>   parents all over the world. As Woolly Mammoth Entertainment, they
>   created and developed the hit radio series *Jungle Jam and Friends the
>   Radio Show!*, which also featured the RazzleFlabbenz and Sing Along
>   with Bert the Moose!   In 1999, Wayne Zeitner from Everland
>   Entertainment joined the team. They changed the name of their company
>   to Fancy Monkey Studios, and are launching brand new programs, still
>   designed to make kids and their parents laugh through **stories that
>   show the goodness of God and the relevance of the Bible**.

### Should you wish to inquire about rights, etc...,:

This is a link to the producer, [Fancy Monkey Studio](http://fancymonkey.com/?Pg=202) and the particular series in question, Jungle Jam, a [link to purchase CD's from them](http://fancymonkey.com/?Pg=404).  The site also has Downloads, CDs, Books, Quizzes, Videos, Contests,
Gift Certificates, and Coloring pages.

A Link for [Amazon with Keywords Everland & Jungle Jam](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Everland+Jungle+Jam&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3AEverland+Jungle+Jam).

An [ebay link to the exact episode, King of the Jungle](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Jungle-Jam-King-Jungle-Everland-Entertainment-Cassette-Tape-/111973063125?hash=item1a121d59d5) for purchase.

[image]

**Tape Contents**, Side One:
In the Jungle
Very Nice Thing to Have a King
I Love to /eat
Fun for Only One
The Whole World's Waiting on Me

Side Two:
Kings Should Not Be Afraid of the Dark
Where Can We Find a King?
These Things Are Hard for Me
Jesus is Our King
In the Jungle (Reprise)

### And finally, an interview with the producer--Jeff Parker

[A Talk With Jeff Parker](http://ptpopcorn.com/index.php/2009/a-talk-with-jeff-parker/) done in 2009 about the show.